# PHPExcel PDF Layout

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

So I am exporting an Excel file I created with PHPExcel to PDF. My only problem is when the content runs over the width of the page (not the length) that content disappears. Only a blank page is created where that content should be. I've tried inserting a column break with a line like this example from the documentation, but only row breaks seem to work with PDF:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setBreak( 'D10' , \PHPExcel_Worksheet::BREAK_COLUMN );
```

It's worth mentioning I'm working from within a Symfony2 controller, hence the slash in front of the PHPExcel enum.

My ideal solution is to have any extra content run over to a second page that can be placed alongside the first page to show the entire table as it appears in a real Excel document.

Comment: can you switch the pay layout from portrait to landscape?

Comment: I can, but my content can be infinitely wide so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the external library used by PHPExcel to render html output as PDF (namely tcPDF).

While I'm aware of a number of other libraries that can generate PDF from HTML (such as domPdf and mPdf) and future versions of PHPExcel will allow you to select which of these libraries you wish to use, none of them seem capable of generating multiple pages to show data from the full width of a worksheet.

Unless anybody can suggest alternatives, I'm afraid that this will remain a limitation for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My solution was just to lay everything out manually and fit what I could on one page by shrinking the fonts and using very thin borders.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem vertically, 
the solution i found was to use this

```
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->getHighestRow();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setPrintArea("A1:I" . $highestRow )
    ->setFitToHeight(255);
```

i would suggest trying something similar with width.
for example :

```
   $highestColumn= $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->getHighestColumn();


    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->getPageSetup()
        ->setPrintArea("A1:" . $highestColumn . "10" )
        ->setFitToWidth(255);
```